# Error querying postgresql table created in pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4, quoted-identifier

I have successfully created a table in pgAdmin which generated the code:

```
CREATE TABLE public."Test3"
(
    "PID" integer,
    "Name" character varying(20),
    PRIMARY KEY ("PID")
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public."Test3"
    OWNER to postgres;
```

However when I try to query the table with:

```
Select * from Test3;
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR:  relation "test3" does not exist 
LINE 1: Select * from Test3;
                      ^ 
SQL state: 42P01 Character: 15
```

Same thing happens if I leave out the TABLESPACE line. Same thing happens if I try to query a table after importing rows from a .csv file. Seems like I must be missing something obvious.

Edit: I am trying to create the table in a database named "ABR"

Comment: You should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: Ah, thanks for the reference. Silly me for thinking of SQL as case-insensitive. Guess I need to get out of the CamelCase habit

Comment: SQL **is** case-insensitive - as long as you don't use those dreaded double quotes. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL implicitly converts all the SQL that you enter into lower case, unless you wrap things in double-quotes in which case you have to get the case *exactly* right.

Wherever possible, you should avoid *needing* quotes or other wrapper characters, i.e. don't use special characters in identifier names.  It will only come back to bite you.

```
create table public.test3
( pid integer
, name character varying(20) 
, primary key (pid)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The quotes, my friend, don't forget the quotes.

```
Select * from "Test3";
```